# C++ input from file in vim

Tags: c++, windows, vim

I have a C++ file `code.cpp`, and an input file `input.txt`. After compiling, I want to run the file from vim like `code.exe < input.txt`. Doing `!$code_dir < $input_dir` does not work. What's the fix?

Comment: You might be interested in trying [GNU emacs](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/). Running programs from it is really easy.

Answer (score 1):

Vim perfectly supports

```
:!path/to/executable < other/path/to/file
```

It doesn't work with `:term path/to/exec < path/to/file` though -- unlike neovim that has no troubles here.

Given the simple

```
#include <iostream>
int main()
{
    std::string line;
    while (std::getline(std::cin, line)) {
        std::cout << line << "\n";
    }
}
```

compiled with `:make %<` (I'm using g++-cygwin and not g++-mingw), `:!./%< < %` works perfectly.

In case what I've just described doesn't work, as I see a `windows` tag, maybe your `&shell*` options are incorrectly set? With Windows, I had to change the default as I use the native gvim with cygwin. In a pure windows environment, I make sure [my settings are](https://github.com/LucHermitte/vim-system-tools/blob/master/plugin/system_utils.vim#L268) (don't ask me why, this is the result of 15-20 year old experimentations and I definitively don't remember all the tests I made)

```
let &shell=$COMSPEC
set shellslash
set shellcmdflag=/c
set shellquote=
set shellxquote=
set shellredir=>
set shellpipe=>
```

Comment: Restrict them to the case `has('win32')` is detected. Otherwise, you'll mess your configuration on *nix systems.